# How to I use a variable from the shiny UI outside of a reactive environment?

Tags: r, shiny

**Situation**: I have one input where you can choose "small" or "big", a csv-file with data and another input, where you can choose from a list from the csv depending on your choice of "small" or "big".

**Problem**: I cannot find a way to access the variable `input$selecter` in the `updateSelectizeInput` function.

Here is my minimal code example which unfortunately does not work:

```
library(shiny)

ui=fluidPage(
  selectInput('selecter', "Choose ONE Item", choices = c("small","big")),
    selectizeInput('chooser', 'Choose SEVERAL Items', choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
)

server=function(input,output,session){
 DatafromMytable=read.csv("mytable.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
 # mysubset=subset(DatafromMytable,Size=="big") #
   mysubset=subset(DatafromMytable,Size==input$selecter)
 updateSelectizeInput(session, "chooser", choices = mysubset$Item) 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Question**:
What do I need to change in the line `updateSelectizeInput(session, "chooser", choices = mysubset$Item)` to make the code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution seems to be to just wrap the two lines that have reactive variables with `observe({ ... })`.

```
 observe({  
 mysubset=subset(DatafromMytable,Size==input$selecter)
 updateSelectizeInput(session, "chooser", choices = mysubset$Item) 
 })
```

Comment: If you do not need the contents of the subsetted dataframe anywhere else, this is actually a very simple and elegant solution! +1

Answer (score 3):

You have to make your variable `mysubset` into a reactive, and then call its value with `mysubset()`. Also, you need an observer that fires the `updateSelectizeInput` whenever it sees that `mysubset()` has changed.

Example below. Note that I have commented out your `read.csv` statement, and added some sample data to make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)

ui=fluidPage(
  selectInput('selecter', "Choose ONE Item", choices = c("small","big")),
  selectizeInput('chooser', 'Choose SEVERAL Items', choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
)

server=function(input,output,session){

  #DatafromMytable=read.csv("mytable.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
  DatafromMytable=data.frame(Size=c('small','small','big','big'),Item=c(1,2,3,4))

  mysubset= reactive ({
    subset(DatafromMytable,Size==input$selecter)
    })

  observeEvent( mysubset(),{
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "chooser", choices = mysubset()$Item) 
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could it be, that the comma in the line 'observeEvent( mysubset(),{' is a typo?

Comment: It is indeed not a typo. You should be able to copy this code in a new file in RStudio and run it without errors. What makes you think it is a typo? Maybe I can elaborate.

Comment: You are absolutely right @Florian. It is not a typo.